# How Gulp tasks added from different files persisting

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

So far my understand about JS modules were,

1. Unless function, objects etc. is not exported from the JS module its
   useless and no code in module gets executed (except direct calls ex:
   console.log(), somefunction() that too if its requir()'ed by other module).
2. So always let module to export
   something.
3. Also every time require('moduleName') is called new object is returned
4. Function, variables declared in one module not accessible from other
   modules (unless exported)

But while looking at one [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) tasks implementation today i am puzzled and wanted to understand why gulp task are getting added though declared/added in other JS files.

Following is the example

**project/a/a.js** file

```
var gulp= require('gulp');
gulp.task('task:a', function(){
    console.log('module:a task task:a executed')
});
module.exports = {
    strA: "strA"
}
```

**project/b/b.js** file

```
var gulp= require('gulp');
gulp.task('task:b', function(){
    console.log('module:b task task:b executed')
});
module.exports = {
    strB: "strB"
}
```

**project/gulpfile.js** file

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
// require() called without using exported elements
require('./a/a.js');
require('./b/b.js');

gulp.task('task:in:gulpfile');
```

Now if you try following in command line

```
cmd>gulp -T 
op: 
...
[--:10:07] ├── task:a
[--:10:07] ├── task:b
[--:10:07] └── task:in:gulpfile

cmd>gulp task:a
module:a task task:a executed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `gulp` is a shared instance object. When you are requiring it in your `a.js` and `b.js`, as it's being required on `gulpfile.js`, the shared instance `gulp` is called when `.task` method is called.

If you look at the source code here: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/index.js#L63

You can see that

```
var inst = new Gulp();
module.exports = inst;
```

You can read more about that here: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Pretty much when you export an instantiated object, that object is cached in require as-is. If you were to use the same require, you will be getting that same instance.